# Android Studio, Emulator not running newest version

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android studio project, which builds with 0 errors and 0 warnings, however when the emulator starts up it is a old version of my application.

I have tried wiping data from the emulator, rebuilding the project, cleaning the project, restarting the machine, creating a new virtual machine.

My debug log;

```
        02-05 02:28:53.197    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app E/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10053: Read-only file system
        02-05 02:28:53.197    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app W/Zygote createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
        02-05 02:28:53.198    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
        02-05 02:28:53.242    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app W/ActivityThread﹕ Application uk.ac.app.app is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
        02-05 02:28:53.246    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk 
        02-05 02:28:53.299    1759-1766/uk.ac.app.app I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
        02-05 02:28:54.662    1759-1766/uk.ac.app.app I/art﹕ Debugger is active
        02-05 02:28:54.719    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
        02-05 02:28:54.720    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
        02-05 02:28:54.924    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
        02-05 02:28:55.137    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
        02-05 02:28:55.345    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
        02-05 02:28:55.563    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
        02-05 02:28:55.806    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
        02-05 02:28:56.014    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
        02-05 02:28:56.224    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
        02-05 02:28:56.437    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
        02-05 02:28:56.645    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
        02-05 02:28:56.865    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1511)
        02-05 02:28:58.737    1759-1759/uk.ac.app.app D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
        02-05 02:29:06.263    1759-1771/uk.ac.app.app I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1867(113KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 387KB/623KB, paused 2.030ms total 112.509ms
```

Comment: Create a new AVD, and delete the old version.

Comment: dont use android avd, use Genymotion emulator

Comment: @Apurva, Genymotion is not suitable when you need arch different from x86.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was a broken XML file in the res directory.